# C# get datagrid cells with checbkox to query

Tags: c#

i have datagrid view with database names. I Want to use them in query. i Will select them with checbox. I Make a button who make this query. My question is how can i make parameter from checked cells in datagridview?
This is button code:

```
private void UpdSalaryMonthTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = item.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;


                if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
                { 
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"USE @Name

    Update VariablesHistory
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)   
    Update ContractFormulaSalaryHistory
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)  
    Update FormulaSalaryHistory
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)

    Update ValueSalary
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) 
    Update SalaryMonth
    set [Month] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Month] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)

    Update LengthOfService
    set [Month] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Month] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)


    Update Dekl1Value
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
    Update Dekl1FormulaHistory
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
    Update Dekl6Value
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
    Update Dekl6FormulaHistory
    set [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)


    --Update TaxRecalculationFormulaHistory
    --set   [Date] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)", connection);


                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated!", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry i'm new in C# with self studying. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using `@Name` will make it consider as a string value instead of a database name.
A better option would be to use `ChangeDatabase` method to change the name of your database before executing the command.

```
connection.ChangeDatabase("your database name from the datagrid cell or from anywhere view here ")
```